# Psycopg2 command hangs, possibly because of table name?

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

The code below hangs (even ctrl-C won't stop it, I have to close the terminal) when it tries to create the second table, and I'm not sure why. The first table is created successfully (I can see it in psql with \dt cyanobacteria.*). A simple solution would be to rename the table, but I'm trying to restore someone else's code to working order and I'd have to go through changing lots of stuff. And he had it working once, so it ought to work for me!

I've created a database called 'genomes', a user called 'genomes_admin' and a schema called 'cyanobacteria'. Then I try to make some tables:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2

psql = "dbname='genomes' user='genomes_admin'"
schm = 'cyanobacteria'

conn = psycopg2.connect(psql)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SET search_path TO %s''', (schm,))
conn.commit()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testnm(blah text, length int) ''')
print 'created testnm'
conn.commit()
print 'committed'

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genomes(blah text, length int) ''') # hangs here
print 'created genomes'  # this line never executes
conn.commit()
print 'committed'
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Is the table structure really `blah text, length int`? I assume you have replaced your actual structure with a dummy placeholder, but does your script _still_ hang with the dummy structure?

Comment: Check `pg_locks`, also examine `pg_stat_activity`. See: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring .

Comment: @Ianzz - yes, that's not actually the table structure! But the script does still hang with the dummy structure.